# Does '8.5.6 ‘grep’ regular expression syntax' in findutils' manual refer to `grep`'s syntax for BRE or ERE?

Tags: grep, find, regular-expression

1. `grep -G` supports Basic Regular Expressions, `grep -E` Extended
   ones, and `grep -P` Perl ones.

   Does Section '8.5.6 ‘grep’ regular expression syntax' in findutils'
   manual
   https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#grep-regular-expression-syntax
   refer to `grep`'s syntax for Basic Regular Expressions or Extended
   Regular Expressions?

   Note that findutils' manual has a different section for '8.5.3
   ‘egrep’ regular expression syntax'
   https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#egrep-regular-expression-syntax.
   Does it mean that the answer to my question is for BRE?
2. Does findutils' manual have descriptions for various kinds of
   regular expression syntaxes  up-to-date or outdated in most
   important parts
   https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Regular-Expressions?

Thanks.

Comment: "Outdated" compared to what?

Answer (score 1):

The first section linked in your point 1, `8.5.6` is the standard for `grep` under the `BRE` syntax. The second section linked in your point 1, `8.5.3` is the standard syntax for `grep` under the `ERE` syntax. The section linked to in your point 2 is at the top of the same group. If you scroll down you will find `8.5.3` and `8.5.6` on the same page. Instead of scrolling down, you can simply click the links at the bottom of `8.5` and it will scroll directly there. **All** of those section *are* on the same page, just higher or lower on it.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean that the answer to my question is for BRE?

Yes. `grep` should be equivalent to `grep -G` and `egrep` should be equivalent to `grep -E`. By default the `elisp` syntax is used. See the [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/regex.h#n219) for a full feature set.

> Does findutils' manual have descriptions for various kinds of regular expression syntaxes up-to-date or outdated in most important parts?

It's "up-to-date" enough for the most part, and it was generated with an [automated tool](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/lib/regexprops.c) some time ago, so there is little room for human error.

Still, a few newer features, such as [equivalence classes](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Equivalence-Class-Operators.html#Equivalence-Class-Operators) and [collating symbols](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Collating-Symbol-Operators.html#Collating-Symbol-Operators) are not mentioned. You can refer to the [gnulib documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expressions.html#Regular-expressions) (which is the underlying library that `grep` and `find` use) to read about those.